# Extracting data from HTML tag using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to extract EXPERIENCE field from the below html

```
<html><head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
</head><body>
<span></span>
<div><a>Page 1</a></div>
<div><span>XYZ 
<br/></span></div><div><span>8</span><span>th</span><span> Semester Undergraduate | Computer Science Engineering | UCE RTU, Kota 
<br/></span></div><div><span>+91 1234567890 | ABCD@gmail.com | 7/108, Malviya Nagar Jaipur (302017)</span><span>
<br/></span></div><div><span>SUMMARY 
<br/></span></div><div><span>
<br/></span></div><div><span>To seek an opportunity to apply my technology expertise along with my creative problem solving skills in an 
<br/>innovative software company. 
<br/></span></div><div><span>
<br/></span></div><div><span>EXPERIENCE</span><span>
<br/></span></div><div><span>
<br/></span></div><div><span>
<br/></span></div><div><span>•</span><span> </span><span>Machine Learning Engineering Intern , Forsk Technologies , Jaipur  (May,2017 – July,2017)    </span><span>
<br/></span></div><div><span>Learned the foundational concepts of data science and machine learning including python and statistics, 
<br/>enough time was spent on understanding the concept behind each algorithm and examples and case 
<br/></span><span>studies were done. Built some mid-scaled machine learning models using supervised and unsupervised 
<br/></span><span>learning.</span>
<span>
<br/></span></div><div><span>•</span><span> </span><span>Software Engineering Intern , Proxbotics Creations Technologies , Jaipur (May,2016 – July,2016)</span><span>
<br/></span></div><div><span>Developed  and  optimized  various  projects  including  ecommerce,  booking  &amp;  reservation,  non-profit 
<br/>organization Websites, using technologies: HTML, CSS, PHP, JavaScript, MySQL etc.                         </span><span>
<br/></span></div><div><span>•</span><span> </span><span>Trainee at TecheduSoft , Kota  (May,2015)</span><span>
<br/></span></div><div><span>The course contains 15+ modules including Android Basics, fragments, screen designing, intents, various 
<br/>views, signing app, web servers, web services, notifications, etc.
<br/></span></div></body></html>
```

But unable to get the required output

Expected output:
Machine Learning Engineering Intern , Forsk Technologies , Jaipur  (May,2017 – July,2017)
Learned the foundational concepts of data science and machine learning including python and statistics,
enough time was spent on understanding the concept behind each algorithm and examples and case
studies were done. Built some mid-scaled machine learning models using supervised and unsupervised
learning.

Software Engineering Intern , Proxbotics Creations Technologies , Jaipur (May,2016 – July,2016)
Developed  and  optimized  various  projects  including  ecommerce,  booking  &  reservation,  non-profit 
organization Websites, using technologies: HTML, CSS, PHP, JavaScript, MySQL etc.

Trainee at TecheduSoft , Kota  (May,2015)
The course contains 15+ modules including Android Basics, fragments, screen designing, intents, various 
views, signing app, web servers, web services, notifications, etc.

Comment: Is there much more html? It would help to have the full properly formed html. Or at least up to the next section you wish to exclude.

Comment: @QHarr I have edited the question. Could you help me out here?

Comment: @QHarr It's returning null for me. Dint work.

Answer (score 0):

One way is use bs4 4.7.1 + and :has and :contains. This assumes bullet points are for experience section. Otherwise, you can filter to sibling divs of EXPERIENCE with:

```
for i in soup.select('div:has(span:contains("EXPERIENCE")) ~ div:has(span:contains("•"))'):
```

py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for i in soup.select('div:has(span:contains("•"))'):
    print(' '.join([i.text.strip(), i.next_sibling.get_text().strip().replace('\n',' ')]))
```

[image]